# Using local tiles with React Native Maps

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am a beginner with React Native.

I'm using **Expo** on **Windows 10** and testing on an **iPhone**.

I need to create a map with custom tiles.
After some research I find out that Leaflet is not React Native compatible so I have to use react-native-maps.

I install it and create my first basic map, so far so good (Apple Maps).

Then I tried to apply the custom tiles. For performance reasons I want to use local tiles. Here came the question of how to get the local link of my tiles (located in "assets/tiles").

While searching I realize that I need to use **react-native-fs** to use the following path `file://${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}`.
I install it.
However, when I try to add **react-native-fs** using

`var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');`

I get the error :

> Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.

and I'm lost and don't know if I'm going the right way.

Thanks

Comment: Expo doesn't support the react-native-fs module. Native modules cannot be installed on a expo project if it does not support it. You can use the FileSystem api as an alternative https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I'm sorry I'm taking over this file after a long absence.

I still can't use my custom tiles for MapView, and I can't limit my map view to those custom tiles. I'm getting desperate...

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Sorry, i've never used maps before..